# Can you connect the Visual Studio debugger to IronPython Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I use IronPython for a lot of debugging, and I usually attach my Visual Studio debugger to `ipy.exe`, then import and use a .NET assembly to step through my code.  However, I find that the IronPython Interactive extension for VS2010 is more fully-featured than the `ipy.exe` shell, and I would like to know whether it is possible to attach the debugger to the extension.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project file (not the solution) Proprieties/ Debug. 
Then you should select "Standrad Python Louncher" for launch mode. It will use the ipy.exe, for interpeter, just you can debug easier. 
You sould make visible the "Python Debug Interactiv" from Debug menu